# What's the largest allowed image size for SageMaker GroundTruth Labelling Job?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

We have images of single size 400 MB to 800 MB.

Not sure if SageMaker GroundTruth can handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/input-data-limits.html

In case someone is also looking for the answer of this one.

In short:

> 40 MB